# Reciprocal relationship between persons

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine-orm

I'm developing a small app to manage persons and their relationships.

I created a model for relationships on the same "level" like marriage and siblings. To represent parents and children I use self referencing fields.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efc90/12/0)

[image: EER]

The idea behind this is, to have reciprocal relationships between persons without violating any NF's and to avoid duplicates.

My problem is, that the query to get all persons which are related to a person is complex since with a normal join the corresponding person would be in the resultset too.

Is there a way to query all persons related to person A without having person A in the resultset?

Is there a better way to represent reciprocal relations?

Comment: Just a tip. Just dropping a goofy image is barely helpful. We need the output of `show create table xyz` where xyz are the relevant tables. Then some sample data, and some expected results. People do this in columns of faked data. The Awesome People do this with SQLFiddle and share the url so we don't have to waste all our time making it for you. When you don't do that, we flee and don't help. So, that is constructive criticism you can think about as for why nothing is solved half the time.

Comment: @Drew Didn't thought about this tool when I was writing the question. I added a SQL Fiddle for both question and answer. Thank you for your constructive feedback.

Comment: I apologize for sounding like a jerk. Just want people to get their answer. :p

Comment: @Drew It didn't sound like this to me - I'm here to learn so I'm open to any form of constructive feedback :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `where` clause to filter out person A from the resultset. Self join the persons_relationships table on itself, filtering for person A (with the id of x) in one instance, and excluding the same person from the other one:

```
select 
  pr2.person_id 
from
  persons_relationships pr1
inner join 
  persons_relationships pr2 on pr1.relationship_id=pr2.relationship_id
where 
  pr1.person_id=x and pr2.person_id<>x;
```

[Sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efc90/7/0)

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please give me a tipp how to get the persons and not just the id? My attempts using a join weren't succesful.

Comment: @berkyl it is a simple inner join on the pr2 alias.

Comment: thank you, my problem with the join was a wrong order of the joins.